# Return elements of list as independent objects in global environment

Tags: r, environments

I have a list, and would like to break the elements of the list into seperate objects in the global environment.

For example, I would like the list:

```
obj <- list(a=1:5, b=2:10, c=-5:5)
```

to be three seperate objects `a`, `b`, and `c`.

I tried to achieve this with:

```
lapply(obj, FUN = function(x) names(x)[1] <<- x[1])
```

But it failed, with `Error in names(x)[1] <<- x[1] : object 'x' not found`.

How might I achieve my aim?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is special function for mapping list to environment:

```
> obj <- list(a=1:5, b=2:10, c=-5:5)
> ls()
[1] "obj"
> list2env(obj,globalenv())
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> ls()
[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "obj"
```

P. S. It is my comment provided as an answer

Answer (score 10):

This also would work:

```
lapply(seq_along(obj), function(i) assign(names(obj)[i], obj[[i]], envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: You might want `obj[[i]]` instead, so that you assign vectors, and not one element lists.

Comment: Please not Dason's does what you want as well with less headache.

Comment: @ricardo, please take a look at Gregory's comment to your question. -- (the other)

Comment: I don't like to attach data, ever. Is there a good reason to break this rule?

Comment: @ricardo Gregory's answer isn't using `attach` (which is a bad idea and why I don't recommend it).  Then again if you don't like attaching data why are you doing what you want to do in the question instead of working directly with the list itself?

Comment: No shame in unchecking this answer and selecting Gregory's.

Answer (score 1):

In case the list isn't yet a named list, we need to set names first, e.g. with incrementing letters.

```
obj2 <- list(1:5, 2:10, -5:5)

list2env(setNames(obj2, letters[seq(obj2)]), envir=.GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "a"    "b"    "c"    "obj2"
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend it but you could use `attach`

```
> obj <- list(a=1:5, b=2:10, c=-5:5)
> attach(obj)
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> b
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> c
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: This does not what OP asked, it just attaches the object `obj` to the search path. That doesn't mean you assign the elements of the list to independent objects in the global environment. Gregory has the correct answer.

Comment: @JorisMeys Sure but they never really said why they wanted to do this either.  `attach` allows you to pretend like they're a part of the global environment (at least in simple cases) with very little work.  With that said I definitely think Gregory's answer is the best out of the answers given.

Comment: I see why you mentioned it, but the use of `attach` poses a lot more problems than it solves, not in the least when you try to change one of the elements in the list. As said in the [R Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html#attach) : The possibilities for creating errors when using attach are numerous. Avoid it.

Comment: @JorisMeys I agree.  Which is why I don't recommend it.  I also don't really like the whole idea posted in the question though.  There are also dangers associated with Gregory's answer as well too