# How to return elements of R list as independent objects in function environment?

Tags: r

Similar to this question:

[Return elements of list as independent objects in global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795526/return-elements-of-r-list-as-independent-objects-in-global-environment)

I cannot seem to adapt the answer to assign the list elements when `list2env` is called inside a function:

E.g.

```
lst <- list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4))

tmp_fn <- function(lst) {
    # do computations on list elements
    # first assign each to the function environment
    list2env(lst, parent = parent.frame()) # fails

    # do stuff
    ...
}
```

I thought the `parent = parent.frame()` would work, but while debugging `tmp_fn` I only see that `lst` gets assigned to the function environment as a list, not the individual variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: Perhaps you just want to `attach(lst)` in your function? The `pos` argument might be friendlier to work with, and the default `2L` I think does what you want.

Comment: I thought that `attach` is not recommended?

Comment: `attach` isn't recommend, but you're trying to do what `attach` does. The general recommendation would be to use your `list` as you have it.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Use `envir=` here rather than `parent=` like this.  Also, as shown, you may wish to add `envir` as an argument for flexibility:

```
lst <- list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4))

tmp_fn <- function(lst, envir = parent.frame()) {
    invisible(list2env(lst, envir = envir))
}
tmp_fn(lst)
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use `list[...]<-` from the gsubfn package (development version):

```
devtools::install_github("ggrothendieck/gsubfn")
library(gsubfn)

func <- function(lst) lst
list[a, b] <- func(lst)
```

Now `a` and `b` will be in the current environment.

Comment: I have tried your first solution, thanks. It seems like you may have slightly misinterpreted my question. I do not want a function `tmp_fn` that assigns the list objects into the calling environment of `tmp_fn`. Instead, I would like the elements to be assigned into the environment of `tmp_fn` when it is called. Your solution still works as I can do something like. `tmp_fn2 <- function(lst){tmp_fn1(lst)}`, which does assign the `lst` elements into the function environment of `tmp_fn2`. However, I wonder whether there is a more straightfoward way of doing this without defining another function.

Comment: You can specify `envir` to be whatever you want. For example, define the default value of envir as `envir=parent.env(environment())` instead of `envir=parent.frame()`