# Subsetting a dataframe into many dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset, apply

I have a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) that contains `year`, `state`, and `organization type`. The years range from 1970-2018, and there are 6 (or so) types of organizations. I want to separate this dataframe by year and organization.

An example of what I have:

```
Year  State  Type
   1970   AL     A
   1970   AK     B
   .....
   .....
   1975   OH     D
```

What I would like:

**Dataframe 1**

```
  1970  AL     A
  1970  AK     A
```

**Dataframe 2**

```
  1971  AL     A
  1971  AK     A
```

**Dataframe 50**

```
  1970 AL   G
  1970 AK   G
```

**Dataframe 55**

```
  2018 AL   G
  2018 AK   G
```

I have thought some loop/while function could work but have not figured it out. I could subset manually but that will take a lot of time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `split(df, df$Type)`

Comment: I have tried this, but it puts everything into a list. Not sure how to get these components into individual dataframes?

Comment: Each list element is an individual data frame. Do you mean that you want them all listed in your global environment? It's a bad practice. Preferred way is to keep them in the list and simply save the list. If you really want to put them to your global env. then follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795526/return-elements-of-list-as-independent-objects-in-global-environment) has the information you need. Note you can extend `split` to include more columns if needed

Comment: I want to add these data to a larger data set for analyses. I have tried the: do.call("cbind", Dataframe) 

but get this in error: In cbind(AR = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970,  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

The split function is actually exactly what I want. Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: *"add ... to a larger data set"* suggests `do.call("rbind",...)`, not cbind. One good reference for list-of-frames: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272