# Renaming dataframe with parse text R

Tags: r

Why doesn't this code change actually change the column names of TEST?

```
TEST = data.frame(col1 = LETTERS, col2 = letters)
"TEST" %>% paste0(" %<>% dplyr::rename(capitalLetters = 'col1') ") %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()
```

I want to do a series of transforms to a large number of dataframes, where I have a list of the names of the dataframe environmental variable names. But I don't want to manually type out the transform for each dataframe, so I thought to use parse text -> eval.

EDIT: getting rid of the assignment pipe

```
"TEST" %>% 
paste0(
    ., " <- ", ., 
    " %>% dplyr::rename(capitalLetters = col1) "
) %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()
```

EDIT: Just noticed this doesn't work either

```
"A <- 3" %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()
A
Error: object 'A' not found
```

I guess one cannot assign/update environmental variables through parse->eval?

Comment: by any chance you made a typo: `%<>%` instead of `%>%` ?

Comment: not a typo, ```library(magrittr)```, this is a pipe which passes the input into the function on the right AND sets the input equal to the value of the function on the right

Comment: Updated to eliminate assignment pipe

Comment: `"TEST" %>% paste0(" %>% dplyr::rename(capitalLetters = 'col1') ") %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: It works, but it does not assign. The point of this is that I don't want to type the dataframe name TEST, I have a large list of dataframe names (list of environmental variable names of dataframes) all of which need a series of transformations. So I wanted the assignment to be part of the evaluated string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have completely understand the problem. Hope this might help you

```
Dfs<-list(DF1=data.frame(col1 = LETTERS, col2 = letters),DF2=data.frame(col1 = LETTERS, col2 = letters))
DfsNew<-lapply(Dfs,function(x) x%>%rename(capitalLetters = 'col1'))
```

It will create a list with same data frame names and will change `col1` to `capitalLetters` in all of them

Now if you want your dataframes to be in the global enviroment check this
[Return elements of list as independent objects in global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795526/return-elements-of-list-as-independent-objects-in-global-environment)

in our case

```
list2env(DfsNew,globalenv())
```